# Chrome extension that would update facebook group page without reloading page

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome-extension

I have been thinking about this but can't figure out due to lack of familarity with how actually facebook is designed to work. If you can help and point me in right direction that would be helpful.

**Problem:** If you are at a group page and someone post a message you have to reload the page to see the new post. Which is annoying if it turns into chatting.

**Possible solutions:** that i've come up with..

extension detects new notification...somehow decide if it's about the page we are at, if yes then in background load the page get the new data and add the stuff to the page already opened. (don't know if it's even possible with the extension)

2nd idea is load  after detection and confirmation just reload the page and retain all text that's been written and just scroll to that post again. I inspected the post structure it all looked randomly generated string...couldn't tell if any of the class or id were reliable to identify the textbox.

3rd idea is make new page bottom up that relies on some sort of sdk and updates pages as new post come in..(least favorable to me).

4th idea is forget about retaining the text that has been typed, if all inputs are empty and there is new notification reload the page...( i really wish reloading wasn't involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript) and an AJAX post. When the server responds, if nothing extraordinary happened (no access token is expired, your facebook app is allowed), then you can handle whatever you want in the callback.

Comment: can you explain more what is that i should be trying to do... i looked into sdk all i could find is how to connect, and share page.

Comment: I have used Facebook through PHP and .NET libraries, therefore I do not know how you should do this with the Javascript SDK, I only know that you can do it.